# how come back to Application after pressing home button

Tags: android, back-button, kiosk-mode, android-homebutton, minimized

I have an android application, when user presses home or back key, android application will be minimized.

I want to open this application after pressing back or home key. (like  long press in home key and selecting minimized app - I want application do this automatically).

What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: search for kiosk mode in android

Comment: surely this isn't something you can do in your application but rather on your phone instead ? Like on my S5 I can map anything I want. So I can map an app to open for example, but that is done on my phone and not in app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is [Kiosk Mode](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/).
it can disable Android features that can be used to leave your app. The following features are affected:

- The back button
- The home button
- The recent apps button
- The power button
- The volume buttons